# How do you expose events wrapped by a Facade class?

Tags: design-patterns

Consider the following structure:

```
Class A: Method A - Fires Event A
Class B: Method B - Fires Event B
Class C: Method C - Fires Event C

Facade: Method ABC (calls method A, B and C), Fires Event A, B and C.
```

How do you expose events A, B and C? Do you bubble up the event from A, B and C? Do you create another event? Do you expose classes A, B and C and let the client code subscribe to the event?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not expose classes A, B and C, as it breaks the main point of Facade - hiding those classes behind an API, and making code using facade independent of them.

For the same reason, I don't think bubbling the events from A, B and C would be a good choice, although I would consider it if those events were on right level of abstaction and not coupled too tightly with classes A, B and C.

If the events were closely coupled with classes hidden behind a Facade, or too low-level in comparison to the facade API, I think I would roll my own events, possibly wrapping original ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the type of events, and were they're defined. If they are "global" events, then any listeners don't mind if they are getting the Facade or implementation class, probably.

In languages like C# you define your event signature (`delegate`), and you should define any relevant parameters as interfaces, so their implementation is 'irrellevant' to any listeners.

If this is impossible, or the listeners depend heavily on the "implementation", I'd go for wrapping the event rather than bubbling them.

Comment: By wrapping, you mean "catching" the event, "wrap" it then throw the wrapped event?

Comment: Yes. Because (only) then the implementation is hidden to any listeners.